# Anki python scripting: Multiple modules missing

Tags: python, module, anki

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at https://www.juliensobczak.com/tell/2016/12/26/anki-scripting.html

And I'm getting the "listcards.py" basic script set up, having cloned anki and installed the virtual environment as well as the requirements from the anki/requirements.txt file.

However, when I run the script from the tutorial entitled "listcards.py", I get a notice that the module 'anki.sched' is not found.  ("ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anki.sched')

While I could pip install each package, I have a feeling that there must be an underlying reason that these packages are missing- is there a way to have python automatically pull in the named module even if it isn't pre-installed in the manner of how node.js installed referenced dependencies automatically, so that I won't have to manually install every missing package?

Comment: I know it's been a while but did you ever get a solution to this? I'm having similar problems

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. `anki.sched` is a package contained within the anki repository you cloned, so it does exist on your machine. You won't be able to install it using pip.

The solution for me was to write the absolute path of the anki repository you cloned in `sys.path.append` rather than a relative path. For example, if your script exists in `/Users/anki/scripts` and your cloned anki repository exists in `/Users/anki/anki` write this in your script before importing anki modules:

```py
sys.path.append("/Users/anki/anki")
```

rather than this (which is what is provided in the tutorial):

```py
sys.path.append("../anki")
```

I'm not 100% sure why the latter fails, but Anki must be looking for the `anki.sched` module in the wrong place due to the relative reference.

Answer (score 0):

What I did, and I know this is probably not the correct way, is to simply wipe out the root anki folder and copy all the application scripts to it, then the imports worked.